# Android Studio(Increment Final Variable)

Tags: java, android, netbeans, android-studio

I'm having a problem in FINAL Variable.
It's always ask me to declare its as final but if i declare it as Final it can't be incremented.

Here's my code:

```
 for(int i=0;i<longLat.size();i++) {


            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    /*Im having a problem here because i need to load
                     more than one 'POILongLat' so i put it in arrayList
                     but it keeps asking me to make it final*/
                     parameters.put("POILongLat", longLat.get(i));
                    parameters.put("POIAddress", "Addresses");
                    return parameters;

                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);

    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can declare **i** as global variable as you are using it in inner loop

Comment: @KishuDroid that would result in completly unpredictable values of `i` because the place that uses it is not executed the same time the loop runs.

Comment: problem solved. thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with this trick:

```
for(int i=0;i<longLat.size();i++) {
     final int valueThisIteration = i;
     ....
        parameters.put("POILongLat", longLat.get(valueThisIteration));
     ...
 }
```

This way there is a new `final` variable in each iteration and Java is happy.

The reason why it has to be `final` has nothing to do with Android or Android Studio. That's because the scope in which you try use the value of `i` is in a completely different place & the code is executed at a completely different time in maybe even a different Thread. And from that place, your for loop with `i` has probably long finished.

Comment: thank you for this trick. that really helped me. thanks a lot!